# Construct counterexamples regarding bounded variation function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

> 1. Construct a function $f(x)\in C(0,1)$ such that $f'(x)$ exists almost everywhere and $f'(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable while $f\notin $ BV([$0,1$]).
> 2. Construct a function $f(x)\in C(0,1)$ such that $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere for $[0,1]$ while $f\notin $ BV([$0,1$]). Furthermore, is there exists a function $f(x)\in C(0,1)$ such that $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere for $[0,1]$ while for all $[a,b]\subset[0,1], f\notin$ BV([$a,b$]).

For 1., I want to try function of form $x^\alpha \sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$, the case $\alpha=1$ satisfies all the condition but $f'$ seems not Lebesgue integrable. I am tring other posibilities. For 2., I really have no ideas, the continuous condition is too strict for me.

Appreciate any help or hint! Please share your mind!

Comment: The classic example of a continuous non-constant function on $(0,1)$ with $f'(x) = 0$ a.e. is the [Cantor-Lebesgue function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Of course, it is increasing so it is of bounded variation. But you could consider how it might be modified to make a function of unbounded variation.

Comment: Could you  be more specific? I tried many times but the function was either not continuous or bounded variarance.

Comment: If $f$ is the C.L. function, then $$g(x) = \begin{cases}cf\left(\frac2{b-a}(x-a)\right)&x\in \left[a, \frac{a+b}2\right]\\cf\left(\frac2{b-a}(b - x)\right)&x\in \left[ \frac{a+b}2,b\right]\end{cases}$$defines a function on $[a,b]$ that rises from $0$ at $a$ up to a value $c$ in the middle, then drops back to $0$ at $b$, continuous and with $g'(0) = 0$ almost everywhere. By a similar stringing together of scaled C.L. functions, you can uniformly approximate functions which themselves converge to a function of unbounded variation.

Comment: I understand your construction of $g(x)$ (indeed I tried this before), but maybe I got the meaning after "by a similar stringing together of scaled..." wrong. I cannot see their convergence to a required function. Can you write out the first few functions?

Comment: The idea is that you can uniformly approximate any non-vertical line segment with such scaled CL functions. Which means you can uniformly approximate any polygonal (continuous piecewise linear) function. Which means you can approximate any function approximable by polygonal functions. These include functions of unbounded variation.